# CakePHP Auth Module Tutorial--Why is it requesting user/login for these pages?

Tags: cakephp

I have a custom routing setup (which might be cause of issue). As follows:

```
Router::connect('/o/*', array('controller' => 'open', 'action' => 'openinsert'));
Router::connect('/c/*', array('controller' => 'click', 'action' => 'clickinsert'));
```

Under UsersController, I have tried:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    //$this->Auth->allow('add');
    $this->Auth->allow('o/*');
    $this->Auth->allow('clickinsert');
    $this->Auth->allow('open');

}
```

clickinsert and openinsert are both apart of controller 'ClickController' and 'OpenController' respectively.

Nothing from above works.  Is is possible to do what I'm wanting to do w/their default auth setup?  Or will I need to make some major changes?

Answer (score 0):

### AuthComponent::allow

[This method](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AuthComponent.html#_allow):

> Takes a list of actions in the current controller for which authentication is not required, or no parameters to allow all actions.

It doesn't accept urls.

In particular this:

```
$this->Auth->allow('o/*');
```

Is neither the wildcard ( nothing or '*' depending on the version of CakePHP used) nor the name of an action, and this:

```
$this->Auth->allow('open');
```

Is apparently passing the name of a controller so neither of those method calls would do anything.

### There's some confusion here

According to these two routes:

```
Router::connect('/o/*', array('controller' => 'open' <-
Router::connect('/c/*', array('controller' => 'click', <-
```

They point to two different controllers.

> Under UsersController, I have tried:

Anything you put in your users controller is irrelevant for requests that don't use it. Either put the allow calls in the before filter for each controller - or put them in the beforeFilter for your *App* controller (which all controllers inherit from).